# Need advice in whether to get a crown on my tooth...?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health

Well, two weeks ago my upper front tooth came completely out when I slipped. I went to a dentist who put the tooth back in place and told me to wait two weeks to see if my body rejects it or not. I went in today and he told me my body accepted the tooth and that he would do a root canal and put a crown on. My question is, since my tooth is getting stronger and healing on its own, do I need a crown? I really don't want my tooth ground down and put in something that might fall off in a couple of years. What do ya'll think??

Comment: This isn't a great question, but it's at least okay.  It's worth at least one point.  So I gave it its first upvote.

1.  Did you ask your question to your dentist?  If so, what did he say?

2.  Can you go to a second dentist for a free second opinion?

Please [edit] your question and let us know.

Comment: He told me he would put a crown after the root canal. He's the one who put the tooth back in. Going to another dentist would cost me $200+ for examination/x-rays I just want to know if doing a root canal without a crown is plausible.

Comment: A properly installed crown doesn't fall off in a couple years. Aside from that, nobody here can offer better advice than your dentist. He has examined you, we have not. He has a dentistry license, we do not.

Answer (score -1):

If your tooth came completely out, its root has been severely damaged. Putting it back in place is something Im a bit surprised can work, but seems plausible to me.

Now, it is also very probable the interior of your tooth (pulp) is not vascularized anymore, and will come to necrosis soon. That's were you probably need the canal treatment. The crown comes almost naturally after the canal.

See [here](http://www.colgate.com/en/us/oc/oral-health/procedures/root-canals/article/illustrations-root-canal-treatment-from-start-to-finish) for images.

Also, crowns, if well placed (I assume your dentist knows its stuff), can last for 3-20 years (depending of the quality of the material, quality of placement, buccal hygien etc etc).

Comment: Well, my tooth is hardening up and it's been two weeks so far. I am taking Penicillin for infections. I can sorta feel this throbbing (no pain) in my tooth as if blood is flowing to it. I don't think my tooth will suffer from necrosis. I was quoted 3k and my insurance only covers 1k. What's the outcome if I let it heal by its self completely? Will it decay and die?

Comment: @Programmer23 Problem is, the external part of your tooth is maybe healing itself, but the interior part is certainly dying, since it is not connected to your body anymore. If you didn't take antibiotics, you would maybe have already had an infection spot at the root. **Ask your dentist.** You can just try to make a call. To my opinion, no alternative to canal. About crown, you can certainly ask for cheaper alternative, like a metallic one...

Comment: Well, technically it is connected to my body since it was re-attached and my body didn't reject it. Dentist said he liked what he was seeing and it was healing.

Comment: @CareyGregory 1. I did not practice dentistry (?) on what you call _patient_ 2. I made only suggestions 3. I am quite aware of dentistry actually, certainly more than you do

Comment: I don't claim to have dentistry knowledge, and I don't care if you're a world renowned dentist; you haven't examined this person and yet you've declared that he has no alternative to a root canal. That, sir, is practicing dentistry.

Comment: _That's were you **probably** need the canal treatment_

Comment: However you worded it, you made an assertion of fact with nothing to support it. Do replanted teeth revascularize and thrive? I don't know but your answer implies they "probably" don't. Well, says who?